# Mapping SQL tables in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, arcgis-10.3, spatial-database, query-layer

I have several tables in SQL server. I am trying to visualize my data in ArcGIS. However, I have not been able to do so.

I started off my making a database connection in Arc Catalog to my SQL. I did this correctly and I am able to view my data.

Then; I went to ArcGIS 10.3 -> Make Query layer and selected my SQL connection. I then double clicked on the table I wanted. Checked advanced options and validated and clicked next. I then selected the primary key and tried to select the CRS. I could not because it was greyed out. So I decided to continue and finalized. In the end I am only able to see my connection in ArcGIS but no mapped data.

How can I map my data?

[image]

Comment: If there's no geometry, there's no mapping.  Please edit the question to include a screenshot of where you failed to specify a coordinate reference.

Comment: How can I add geometry to the data in my table?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to visualize?  Do you have spatial information for your data?  It can't be mapped if there's no location info to display or link it to directly.

Comment: Is there a geometry column in the table?  If not, you're asking the wrong question

Comment: The data has a Lat/Long column. If mapped it would be a point data. The data in SQL does not have a geometry column in the table. I suppose I would need to build this? How would I do that?

Comment: This question is about using something that doesn't exist.  Please research how to create geometry columns in the database (hint: they need to be in {lon,lat} order to match {x,y} geometry) or how to use an event table in ArcGIS separately.

Comment: Vince you are correct but not entirely, my initial question is still correct because I had no working knowledge that the missing geometry is my error. Now,it looks like in order for me to achieve my goal " my inital question" I will have to build geometry columns in my sql data. I would not be able to use event tables in ArcGIS because I plan on publishing this in Arc Server. Thanks a lot for your help, buddy.

Comment: If you don't want to build the geometry in SQL, it's also possible to do it within ArcGIS Desktop. Read up on [adding x,y coordinate data as a layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm). This would essentially be just an extra step after what you are already doing (by using the [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) tool).

Answer (score 5):

**First, I hope I understand your setup correctly**:

- You have several tables in SQL, some with tabular data and one table containing Lat/Long columns (probably floating/double precision data type).
- You would like to join several data tables together and see the information as points in ArcGIS.

**Possible solution**:

- You should make your join/view directly in SQL, joining data tables with the lat/long table. You will end up with a view that will have a.Col1, a.Col2, b.ColX, b.Lat, b.Long
- With the view created, you can add it to ArcMap using the Add XY Data dialog. It is accesible from File/Add XY Data.
- In the wizzard, select the view from the SQL database, add the Lat and Long columns to Y and X geometry columns.
- latitude is Y-axis, longitude is X-axis for WGS84, which is code EPSG:3844.
- the wizzard creates a new point Event Layer, which can be used in GIS analysis or saved as a distinct layer.

**Problem with using query layer the way you presented**:

Query Layers should be used only if joining geometry tables with data tables, to see the resulting query layer as a geometry in ArcMap. Since your are joining one data table to another, because the Lat/Long is not expressed as geometry (in a SQLGeometry data type) the query Layer will only add a table view in the Table of Contents. You can still use this table to create XY point event layer, similar to the steps described above.